# Using Capybara to match HTML tags in textarea

Tags: html, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a textarea that contains HTML. It's not a rich text editor, it displays all tags as text. In my specs I'd like to be able to match HTML elements inside the content, but what I've tried with Capybara so far has failed.

Given:

```
<textarea><p>hello</p></textarea>
```

The browser displays literally `<p>hello</p>`. However, in my rspec test:

```
puts find("textarea").text #no html tag, just "hello"
puts find("textarea").value #no html tag, just "hello"
find("textarea p").text #unable to find CSS 'textarea p'
```

Switching the capybara node to it's underlying nokogiri element via `.native` shows me that even nokogiri is ignoring the tags:

```
puts find("textarea").native
```

..gives:

```
<textarea class="form-control">hello</textarea>
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are absolutely sure that the code contains the p tags in it right? you can double check by looking at the entire page returned in your test to check it's the same code that you see in the browser.

Comment: The code contains the tags and chrome developer tools confirms it.

Comment: sure, I'd still double check in the test suite so you can be sure that there isn't some factor that's affecting it there (because if you're looking at something slightly different in the browser you need to eliminate that as a source of error).

Comment: Which driver are you using? For Selenium-Webdriver, it appears to work as expected.

Comment: Interesting. This is capybara-poletergeist

Comment: `puts find("textarea").text` worked fine when I used Capybara-Poletergeist - ie I got the expected `<p>hello</p>`. I just had a page with the textarea. Maybe try creating a full working example that reproduces the problem?